# Fixing Uncaught TypeError: "your function" is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code to fill an array with some conditions but each time I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: int_part is not a function

what's the problem here? what I'm missing?

here is the code:

```js
var totalSlides = 4; // total number of slides we have
var lastSlideInt = 20; // numbers of review interactions on the last slide

var n = totalSlides - 1;
var x = lastSlideInt / (n * (n + 1) / 2);

var cal = [];
for (var i = 1; i < lastSlideInt; i++) {
  cal.push(i * x);
}

var indexs = [];
var minus = [];
//
var sum = 0;
var floatSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
  sum += cal[i];
  if (sum >= 1) {
    var pusher = int_part(sum) + int_part(floatSum);
    floatSum += float_part(sum);
    minus.push(pusher);
    indexs.push(i);
  }

}
//


function int_part(y) {
  return int_part = Math.trunc(y);
  float_part = Number((y - int_part).toFixed(2));
}

function float_part(d) {
  int_part = Math.trunc(d);
  return float_part = Number((d - int_part).toFixed(2));
}

console.log(int_part(0.2));
```

I think the error should be somewhere on the if statement:

```
 if (sum >= 1){
      var pusher = int_part(sum) + int_part(floatSum);
      floatSum += float_part(sum);
      minus.push(pusher);
      indexs.push(i);
    }
```

Comment: `int_part = Math.trunc(d);` you reassign your function to a number

Comment: `return` expects a value (not an assignment) and will end the function. Simple example: `function sum(a + b) {   return a + b;   }` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kb2m31tL/

Comment: @ChrisG _return expects a value (not an assignment) and will end the function_.  assignment is also an expression.

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, strictly speaking it is. But since OP isn't assigning to a global variable, it's not just pointless but the reason why the code fails. I personally believe it's fine to teach "wrong" stuff to beginners and mention language quirks like this way, way later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning the functions `int_part` and `float_part` to number inside the body of function. You should only return the values.

```js
var totalSlides = 4;    // total number of slides we have
var lastSlideInt = 20;  // numbers of review interactions on the last slide

var n = totalSlides - 1;
var x = lastSlideInt / (n*(n+1)/2);

var cal = [];
for (var i = 1; i < lastSlideInt; i++ ){
     cal.push(i * x); 
}

var indexs = [];
var minus = [];
//
var sum = 0;
var floatSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    sum += cal[i];
    if (sum >= 1){
      var pusher = int_part(sum) + int_part(floatSum);
      floatSum += float_part(sum);
      minus.push(pusher);
      indexs.push(i);
    }

}
//


function int_part(y){
  return Math.trunc(y);

}

function float_part(d){
  let int_part = Math.trunc(d);
  
  return Number((d-int_part).toFixed(2)); 
}

console.log(int_part(0.2));
```

Comment: @TomMettam That doesn't matter because its function declaration. It will be hoisted to the top of scope(global scope) along with the value.